# How to extract two columns from a text file into a csv file using python?

Tags: python, file, csv

I have recently started reading about file handling and I wanted to store [this](https://www.math.muni.cz/~kolacek/docs/frvs/M7222/data/AutoInsurSweden.txt) dataset into a CSV file making two columns, one for each X and Y. I wrote the following code for this:-

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('insurance_dataset.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines= (line for line in stripped if line)
    grouped = zip(*[lines] * 1)
    with open('dataset.csv' ,'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(grouped)
```

The above code stored both the X and Y in a single row. Can anyone please suggest me modifications to my code so that I can put rows X and Y in two separate columns? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you zip here? And why cannot you process one line at a time?

Comment: You should not write a script by randomly copying blocs of code that you do not understand. `zip` is used for a transposition: lines become rows (and rows become lines). One line at a time is what you can read in Hackerman's answer: read a line, process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or maybe you don't need a csv in order to work with the `Auto Insurance in Sweden` dataset:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.math.muni.cz/~kolacek/docs/frvs/M7222/data/AutoInsurSweden.txt'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

open('AutoInsurSweden.txt', 'wb').write(r.content)

with open('AutoInsurSweden.txt') as f:
    lines_after_11 = f.readlines()[11:]


for line in lines_after_11:
    values = line.split("\t")
    print("X:"+values[0] + ", Y:"+ values[1])
```

Comment: Very interesting technique indeed. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You are wolcome @AnukarshSingh

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for comma-seperated values.
Therefore, in order to split between cells, all you have to do is put a comma between values.

Comment: A csv is indeed a comma separated values file. But it can also use quotes to allow occurences of newlines or separators inside a field. So for some use cases, just adding a comma may be wrong.

Comment: I didn't check the data given. Indeed, you better use quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
import csv
data = []
with open('insurance_dataset.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line[0].isdigit():
            data.append(line.strip().split())     #--->Split by space

with open('dataset.csv' , 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter =';')   #--->Semicolon Seperated
    writer.writerow(["X","Y"])     #---->HEADER
    writer.writerows(data)         #---->CONTENT
```

Comment: I often use VM with little RAM for simple tasks. Why do you load everything in memory when you could process one line at a time?

Comment: @SergeBallesta. I am just give an idea or logic on how to solve the problem. It will also help in code readability

Comment: Why was semicolon used as a delimiter here?

Comment: @AnukarshSingh. I just used it as an example. You can use anything

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a list outside of the context manager to store the lines. Then, un-indent the second context manager. Should do the trick...

```
grouped_list = []

with open('insurance_dataset.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines= (line for line in stripped if line)
    grouped_list.append(zip(*[lines] * 1))
with open('dataset.csv' ,'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(grouped)
```